# Failed to Update MySQL table using Express JS

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express

I am facing difficulties to **update** the following tables (MySQL) by using Express Js.

**productdb.discount**

```
discount_id | discount_name | discount_percent
```

**productdb.product**

```
product_id | discount_id | product_price(original price) | product_latest_price(price after discount) |
```

It works on this way :

1. User update the existing discount table by inserting new discount name, percent and select relevant product that applies the respective discount from the checkbox. The input form is as below:

[image]

2. Hence when submit, it will return the discount info, including the discount_id, and the selected product in array-form according to the assigned product_id.
3. My concept of updating the database table is :

- First, Update the discount table.
- Then, Update all discount_id in product table to null according to the discount_id.
- Update the product latest price to product price.
- Update the discount_id to the product table according to the submitted product array.
- Finally, Update the product_latest_price by calculating the result after multiple with discount_percent.

4. I wrote the Query in Express Promise based and it doesn't execute correctly as it failed to update the product_latest_price(Possibly due to async method). In fact, the code looks messy. Anyone have any idea on updating these tables in a more efficient way, or much cleaner code?

By the way, my code to execute the query is as below.

```
exports.discount_update = (discount_info, discount_id, product_id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connectionPool.getConnection((connectionError, connection) => {
            if (connectionError) {
                reject(connectionError);
            } else {
                connection.query(`UPDATE productdb.discount SET ?
                                  WHERE discount_id = ?`, [discount_info, discount_id], (error, result) => {
                    if (error) {
                        reject(error);
                    } else {
                        connection.query(`UPDATE productdb.product
                                          SET discount_id = null, product_latest_price = product_price
                                          WHERE discount_id = ?`, [discount_id], (error, result) => {
                            if (error) {
                                reject(error);
                            } else if (result.affectedRows >= 1) {
                                for (i = 0; i < product_id.length; i++) {
                                    connection.query(`UPDATE productdb.product
                                                      SET discount_id = ?
                                                      WHERE product_id = ?`, [discount_id, product_id[i]], (error, results) => {
                                        if (error) {
                                            reject(error);
                                        } else {
                                            connection.query(`UPDATE productdb.product AS product
                                                              JOIN productdb.discount AS discount
                                                              ON product.discount_id = discount.discount_id
                                                              SET product.product_latest_price = product.product_price - product.product_price * (discount.discount_percent) / 100
                                                              WHERE product_id = ?`, [product_id[i]], (error, result) => {
                                                if (error) {
                                                    reject(error);
                                                } else if (result.affectedRows >= 1) {
                                                    resolve(result)
                                                } else {
                                                    resolve(result)
                                                }
                                            })
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: `UPDATE productdb.discount SET ? WHERE discount_id = ?` cannot work under any circumstances. This invalid SQL.

Comment: Also it's a bad idea to change the product price in based on a discount. Write the discount into a table. Make a view that calculates the final product price on demand. Leave the base price in the product table alone.

Comment: *ALSO* it''s a bad idea to write the discount ID into the product table. Write the product ID into the discount table instead and leave the product table alone. (Yes, that could mean more than one row in the discount table. That's still better than the other way around.)

Comment: Last, but not least it's a bad idea to run UPDATE statements in a loop. You can get rid of all of these shenanigans when you create/delete "discount" rows that reference products and work with a view, e.g. `product_with_discount`.

Comment: Okay, and one final remark, it's a lot better to use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql instead of rolling your own promise code against the `mysql` package.

Comment: Nope. That query actually worked as I can see the changes in my table once I update the discount_info. Wow, there seems like a lot of bad idea in my design, but I think the relation between discount to product should be One to Many right? As, a product can only have a discount at a time.

Comment: What is a better way to design the product-discount table then? Struggling with this the whole day. By the way, what do you mean by working with a view? Is that a junction table or something?

Comment: I am actually using the promise-mysql.

Comment: Something like this is better: `TABLE discount (discount_id, valid_from, valid_to, percentage)` - `TABLE discount_product(discount_id, product_id)` - `TABLE product (product_id, name, base_price, etc)` - `VIEW product_with_discount (a join between those tables with a calculated final_price column)`.

Comment: ...if you are already using `promise-mysql` then you're using it wrong. You don't need to call `new Promise()` ever, and you should not be using node-style callbacks: `connection.blah(something, (error, result) => {...})` should become `return connection.blah(something).then(result => {...})`.

Comment: Goshh, I guess I need some time to rethink about the database schema.

Comment: The code attached is actually written in model, thus, in controller, it will be like: `discount_model.discount_update(discount_info, discount_id, product_id).then((result) => {...}).catch((err) => {...})`.

Comment: Definitely. The schema you have now will come back and bite you in more than one way. -- I'm not talking about how you use `discount_update` in calling code. I'm talking about everything inside `discount_update`. Tell-tale sign: If your (supposed) promise-based code looks like a Christmas tree with 10 levels of indention, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I think I misunderstand what you're trying to say, and indeed, I did not used `promise-mysql` in my code, and I guess I need to take a look about it. (Tired of the Christmas tree code)